# Java Spring Boot project with Websockets returning status 500 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I'm a student learning how to use Spring Boot to build webapps. I have a project where I am experimenting with websockets.

I am encountering a 500 status error when attempting to connect to the chat on the deployed application.

I've deployed my project [here](http://www.jiujitsurepo.com).
To test, please use the login: gohan@gohan.com / password

When I host the application on my own computer through Spring Tool Suite, the chat functions flawlessly. It is only on my EC2 Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM) instance that I encounter this 500 level error when attempting to connect to the chat.

I have followed the following tutorial for the chat application: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-websocket-chat-example/.

Here is my websocket config file:

```
package com.web.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/channel");
}
}
```

Could someone please explain to me why an application utilizing websockets functions perfectly when hosted locally, but does not when deployed?

Further, could someone provide a solution by which I could understand why this problem occurs?

Comment: I think you should share some server side code. Seems like your STOMP endpoint is not set up correctly. Also take a look at your logs - there may be some information

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have updated my post to include the websocket configuration file where the stomp endpoint would be set up.

Comment: Your websocket config looks fine. How do you deploy the application?

Comment: Also it would be nice to see your Controller class

Comment: https://github.com/bchang1213/javaSpringProject/tree/master/src/main/java/com/brianchang/web/controllers

Here are my controllers.

The app is deployed using a war file and ajp proxy. Are there certain deployment details that might be best for relevance? Thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deploy and run your application (on the Tomcat server) using the following configuration:

```
public class Project1Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Project1Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Project1Application.class, args);
    }
    /*@Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        Connector ajpConnector = new Connector("AJP/1.3");
        ajpConnector.setPort(9090);
        ajpConnector.setSecure(false);
        ajpConnector.setAllowTrace(false);
        ajpConnector.setScheme("http");
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(ajpConnector);
        return tomcat;
    }*/
}
```

To test it, I just packaged it to a ROOT.war and threw it in the `webapps` folder. Websockets worked as expected.

Hope this helps.

PS. [This article](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications) proved to be quite useful to me. Good luck!

Comment: Hey Kirill, thank you so much for your answer! I super appreciate your time. However, I am encountering a problem when attempting to test this solution.

I created a new .war file with Maven Install and then ran the .war file on apache2 with

`sudo a2enmod proxy`
`sudo a2enmod proxy_ajp`

and then created a systemd script to run the war file in my EC2 instance.

I am unable to run the .war file. I see that you disabled ajp in your provided solution. Could you explain to me why my project doesn't require AJP in your code?

Comment: @jhm1213 Hi! Thanks for your feedback. I didn't know that you really needed AJP. I thought that you was just trying to launch your application using an application server. So if you also want to configure an AJP connector, then you should dig a little deeper. I guess that because AJP works over HTTP, you may have to add some specific settings to make it work over `ws://` protocol too. Take a look at [this](http://www.elitekeyboarder.com/?p=246) post.

Comment: This looks like a very promising article! Thanks so much for your expertise. I'll comment back to confirm if this solves my problem.

Comment: @jhm1213 Hope it helps!